# C++ Boost library - passing Shared pointer to a function

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, scoped-ptr

Assuming shared pointer can be created as follows

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<Employee_t> srdpointer;     
srdpointer ptr((Employee_t*)malloc(sizeof(Employee_t)),std::ptr_fun(free));
```

I need to pass the shared pointer which will allocate memory Pointed by the ptr.
Something like this.

```
void allocateBlocks(int **ptr, int *cnt)
{
    *ptr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
    *cnt = 10;
    /*do something*/ 
}

int main()
{
    int *p = NULL;
    int count = 0;
    locateBlocks(&p, &count);

    /*do something*/

    free(p);
}
```

How can I achieve the similar functionality using `shared_ptr` as shown in above code.

Comment: may I ask why you are using `malloc` and not `new`?

Comment: Looks, like std::vector<int> will suit your needs.

Comment: Are you aware, that `reset()`ing `shared_ptr` instance with new pointer, does not change other `shared_ptr` instances (they will point to the old object)?

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
void allocateBlocks( boost::shared_ptr<int>& out, int& count )
{
  out.reset(new int[...]);
  count = 10;
}
```

PS: I suggest having a look at boost::shared_array<> & friends for just allocating arrays dynamically.

PS: Would an std::vector<> also do?

Comment: "may I ask why you are using malloc and not new" - Our application is a mix of C and CPP code.

Comment: -1 Passing `malloc`-ed memory to a construct that will free it with the `delete` operator.